# SonataAdminBundle custom group icon

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm using SonataAdminBundle to generate a CRUD for my Page entity.

With the yaml file bellow the menu is displayed in the sidebar.

I would like to change the group default icon which is "fa fa-folder".

But I don't find the option to do it.

```
sonata.admin.page:
        class: FM\AppBundle\Admin\Page\Page
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "CMS", label: "Pages" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - FM\AppBundle\Entity\Page\Page
            - ~
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"icon" option:

```
icon: "<i class=\"fa fa-folder\"></i>"
```

In your example:

```
sonata.admin.page:
        class: FM\AppBundle\Admin\Page\Page
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "CMS", label: "Pages", icon: "<i class=\"fa fa-folder\"></i>" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - FM\AppBundle\Entity\Page\Page
            - ~
```