# Change left menu labels on Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

How can I change the labels in the left menu of my Sonata Admin installation?

I would like to change (and understand how they are generated):

1. The "admin" text
2. The "PostCategory" label (and change it to something more "WordPress-ish" :) like "Post Categories")

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These labels are defined in the `tags` property in the service definition of your admin page, in the config file of the admin section. See documentation [here](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/dashboard.html#using-the-admin-service-declaration).

Example in a `admin-services.yml` file:

```
services:
  app.admin.category:
    class: AppBundle\Admin\CategoryAdmin
    tags:
      - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "My Admin Group", label: "Post Categories" }
    arguments:
      - ~
      - AppBundle\Entity\Category
      - ~
    calls:
      - [ setTranslationDomain, [AppBundle]]
```

The `group` tag corresponds to your `admin` label, and the `label` one to your `PostCategory`.

I guess you didn't specify these tags, and `admin` is the default group name, and `PostCategory` the name of your class.

**EDIT:**

The `label` and the `group` option are translation keys. You specify the translation domain under the `calls` tag, with `setTranslationDomain`, and the default catalog is `messages`. See documentation on translation [here](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/translation.html#translation).

Comment: Is it possible to specify an icon for a group? Is the group a string or a translation key? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can add an `icon` tag also, see example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569887/sonata-admin-bundle-custom-group-icon